How to generate package-lock.json back in a date?
I'm trying to modify a JS/node project which has package.json but not package-lock.json file committed. The author also does not have the original package-lock.json because newer versions has been developed.
However, generating a new package-lock.json makes the project failure to run, due to changes in the dependencies. This is because the generation happens now and uses the up-to-date (compatible) dependencies.
So, is there a way to generate a package-lock.json as if it was generated back at a specific date/time in history, using the up-to-date dependencies back then?
For manually debugging or relying on conventions
Unfortunately it's very hard to tell (at least for a non-JS-native developer like me) which package is failing or to rely on SemVer. This is because the project is essentially a Zotero extension, which means:

It has to be packaged and loaded into Zotero for testing, and the package is compiled/packaged in to bundled JS files such that dependency/library information is gone; and
There are special restrictions under Zotero's JS environment (rather than a standard node environment).


Is the previous package.json available in the git repo?

Do you know what package it's failing on, and what date your wanting to role back too?

You will have to update whichever components/functions/features are failing manually.

@moonbrew Yes it is, and that's how I generate package-lock.json. But unfortunately SemVer doesn't work in this context.

@Keith No I don't know which package it's failing on (see added section in question). I can find the commit date, and use that as a proxy. Manually debugging from then may be viable, but not from now.

Did you try modifying each dependency's version range to exact versions instead of ranges? (e.g. listed in package.json: "typescript": "^5.5.3" -> modify to: "typescript": "5.5.3")

@jsejcksn That's something I did not want to try initially, as I was worried about version conflicts due to that. But yes, it does work. In the meantime, it makes it hard to gradually test and update the dependencies to recent versions, I believe, due to version conflicts in those dependencies?

^ @renyuneyun Any time you update any dependency, you must be prepared to audit/review and potentially refactor — the code that your code uses is equally your responsibility, and unfortunately you can't rely on dependency publishers to respect semver, etc. — although I suspect many devs lack the resources for thorough code review when updating dependencies… but none of that is related to the question you asked. Does the suggestion in my initial comment meet your needs / would you like to see it as an answer?

@jsejcksn Thanks for that. I found an ideal answer today, and added that below. But if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll still give it an upvote as it indeed helps, and does not involve external tools.

After searching around harder, I found an answer to the question myself: use the npm-registry-time-machine project.
It sets up a proxy to npm registry on my local computer, and automatically filters out newer versions of packages, according to the date argument.
What I need to do is:

Start npm-registry-time-machine with the date from git commit
Configure npm to use localhost:3000 as the registry (see its documentation)
npm i as usual in the project

p.s. Thanks everyone for your comments and suggestions.

The point of package-lock.json is to get a record of package versions at a specific point in time. There's no secondary way to get this with out of the box tooling.
Is it possible to accomplish this? Yes, you could write a set of scripts that talk to the NPM api and find release dates for each package before a given date.
Note that if you uses semver, and any packages that use semver shouldn't ideally have a problem like this, because as long as the first digit didn't change, they should have remained compatible. So you might only have to deal with a few bad apples. You're more screwed if you used * for versions everywhere.
Regardless I would imagine that unless you have a very high number of packages, it will be easiest to run through the likely culprits and find era-appropriate versions to install and test again. A good test suite would help with this as well.

Thanks for the info. Unfortunately SemVer doesn't work in this context (because it's failing for the newly-generated package-lock.json). I have added some relevant information in the question to explain why.

But speaking of tooling, I am hoping to find some existing ones rather than having to craft it myself. I can't believe only very few people encounter this issue...

@renyuneyun I think Evert's point is that the SemVer should protect you from updates, eg.  Inside package.json a version like  ^2.0.0 should only update for version 2,  if version 2.1.0 breaks something then there is a massive problem with that package.

@renyuneyun well it's multiple failings of systems that led you to this. I'd imagine most people would update their codebase the deal with the broken packages.

@Keith Thanks for that, and indeed I get it. It doesn't apply to my case because, for example, v2.0.1 may add a new variable and a new function, which does not break compatibility to v2.0.0 (based on the library developer's view, who believes all modern environments supports it; and indeed they should); but this may have something not compatible with Zotero's JS environment, and breaks the whole extension. I've seen this for, e.g., named group in regex

@renyuneyun  Oh, right, don't know much about Zotero's.   Don't know if there is a tool were you could install from a specific time in the past, but it does actually sound a good idea.  In the mean time you can do -> npm view <pkgName> time that will quickly show you the versions at specific times.  eg. npm view jquery time will show all versions of jQuery with version & datetime.   You could then maybe knock up a quick tool that could then do semvar checking on all your packages based on a specific time.

@Keith "^2.0.0 should only update for version 2, if version 2.1.0 breaks something then there is a massive problem with that package." in my experience, this is extremely common with NPM packages. Overall, I find package maintainers in the JS ecosystem to be extremely sloppy with their versioning. Especially since they also like relying on other packages. So if you have "A" : "^1.0.0" which relies on "B": "^2.0.0" then changing the minor version of either might lead to an incompatibility. It's not just me, since lock files were introduced mainly to deal with these issues.

@VLAZ  Totally agree, that's why I said should & does not.  but it's still the package maintainers fault if a Minor breaks an update.  Major release is where breaking changes are only meant to come.  Saying that I've not had too many problems here using a ^ semver, yes, every now and then I'll have to lock a version, but generally speaking npm update -r usually works.  My biggest issue is usually binary packages where a pre-built hasn't yet been done, and having to setup a build chain at a customers is not really ideal.  So generally speaking I don't bother with lock files.
